# Compare operators custom object java

Tags: java, compare, operators

Is there a plug in that supports compare operations on a custom object?

I would like to use this:

```
class MyTemperatureObject implements Comparable<MyTemperatureObject> {
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyTemperatureObject object) {
       return getValue().compareTo(object.getValue());
    }
}

MyTemperatureObject a;
MyTemperatureObject b;

if (a < b){
    ...
}
```

This gives the compile error:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to MyTemperatureObject
```

But I think that the compiler can use the *Comparable* interface to evaluate this. Or is there maybe a reason that this is not possible or not wisely to do this.

I know that I can use the compareTo function

```
a.compareTo(b) < 0
```

But I think this is better readable/understandable

```
 a < b
```

Comment: `I think this is better readable/understandable a<b`, is not supported in Java for `MyTemperatureObject`.

Comment: And in future if you get another doubt of using `equals` method instead of `==` as it is more readable/understandable, then please refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion).

Comment: You cannot overload operators in java !

Answer (score 5):

In Java, the `<` operator can only be used on numeric types. The compiler will **not** automagically apply the `compareTo` method for object comparisons.

Rewrite your condition as follows:

```
if (a.compareTo(b) < 0){ /* ... */ }
```

The semantics of the `compareTo` method are clearly documented in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), but in essence it boils down to this:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object
>   is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Comment: I think you should explain him the return value of the `compareTo` method as well.

Comment: I know this function I have implemented this function. But what I want is to not use this function.

a < b is more understandable than a.compareTo(b) < 0

Comment: But what are the downsides for to not support this?

Comment: I don't see any immediate downsides. Dealing with `null` cases would probably be a little bit tricky, as well as dealing with incompatible types. All issues that could probably be solved more or less elegantly, but I can't speculate about the original language designers' motivations.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do like on C++ operator overloading : [Wikipedia - C++ Operator Overloading](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading), then it doesn't exist on java.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer documentation of [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method.

> **Returns:**
>       a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

You can use compareTo method.

```
if (a.compareTo(b) < 0){
    // Your code
}
```

---

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to MyTemperatureObject

**Answer :** Operator overloading is not supported in Java, as it is supported in C++. So you can use `<` / `>` operator for numeric comparison only.

Answer (score 0):

You must use specific class that invoke compareTo method,
Take a look as this tutorial, I hope help you
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm